# ListView items not showing when running the android emulator

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-manifest

I am finding some problems when I try to display the text in a listview.

The code in the ListView class is:

```
    package org.practical.newsupdate;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MenuView extends NewsfeedApp2Activity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuview);
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.menuview, items);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapt);

    }
    }
```

The code for the main.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ScreenTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ScreenTitle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MenuView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.88" android:visibility="visible">
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the string.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, NewsfeedApp2Activity!</string>
<string name="app_name">NewsfeedApp2</string>
<string name="ScreenTitle">ScreenTitle</string>
<string-array name="menu_array">
    <item>NewsPage</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
    <item>Help</item>
    <item>About</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

The code for the main java file is:

```
package org.practical.newsupdate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

  public class NewsfeedApp2Activity extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
}       
 }
```

and the code for the menuview.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menuview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>
```

The androidmanifest.xml file has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.practical.newsupdate"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".NewsfeedApp2Activity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MenuView"></activity>
    <activity android:name="About"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Help"></activity>
    <activity android:name="NewsPage"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Settings"></activity>



</application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your are using the ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) constructor, which expect as the second parameter the id of a text view to display data, but you give it the id of the menuview.xml layout. You should probably use the ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) constructor, e.g.:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.menuview,
    R.id.menuview,
    items);
```

With this you tell your adapter to:

1. Use your menuview.xml layout for each item in the list, and
2. In the menuview.xml layout, use the view with id menuview to display the data

This may not be very clear as you use "menuview" as the name of the layout and as the id of a view inside it...

Edit: And also as the id of your ListView. This may not disturb Android, but this is not good for the clarity of your code :)